# Is there a website that has collection of GeoJSONs?

Tags: data, geojson

I specifically look for GeoJSON for all dry lands in the globe.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Your question has been placed on hold as too broad which is always a risk when asking a one line question because it does not enable you to be specific about things like what you mean by "dry lands", what scale the data should have been captured at, etc.  I recommend using the **edit** button to add details like these now so that your question can be re-opened.  The minimum length for questions (and answers) is normally "about a paragraph".

Answer (score 2):

There are many more sources of shapefiles than geojson, and you can easily convert shp to geojson with [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

For example, you can download the shapefile for the "Ecoregions of the World" [from here](https://www.worldwildlife.org/publications/terrestrial-ecoregions-of-the-world), then convert BIOME 13 (deserts) to geojson with ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco -sql "SELECT * FROM wwf_terr_ecos WHERE BIOME = 13" output.json wwf_terr_ecos.shp
```

To make the geojson smaller, you can try different combinations of `COORDINATE_PRECISION`, `simplify`, and only select the fields you need:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=2 -sql "SELECT ECO_NAME, BIOME, ECO_CODE FROM wwf_terr_ecos WHERE BIOME = 13" output2.json wwf_terr_ecos.shp -simplify 0.000001
```